# Expand or collapse navigation pane in Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have implemented the navigation pane feature in Power BI report as shown below. I like to expand or collapse this navigation pane to utilize page for visuals.

[image]
Is there any visuals/tricks to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your report/page layout as a bookmark (`Menue Bar > View > Bookmarks Pane`) with the navigation pane visible (`NavigationVisibleBookmark`).

You can trigger visuals visible/invisible with the eye symbol in the selection pane (Menue Bar > Views > Selection Pane`).

Then save another bookmark with the navigation pane invisible (`NavigationInvisibleBookmark`).

Now you can trigger the two different bookmarks with a button for example. Add a blank button and go to the `Properties > Action` and choose `Type = Bookmark` and `Bookmark = NavigationVisibleBookmark`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check on this and get back to you incase need any more clarifications...